# Высота основного блока при нефиксированной высоте шапки - есть ли решение на чистом CSS?

Tags: вёрстка, css, height

Веб-страница ограничена размерами окна браузера. Ни горизонтальной, ни веритикальной прокрутки нет. Для этого используем обертку с абсолютным позиционированием:

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;  
  top: 5px; 
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

Внутри обложки есть шапка и контейнер для контента.

```
.header,
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111;
}

.container {
  background-color: #333;
  /* CSS-магия */
}
```

Шапка не имеет фиксированной высоты. При изменении ширины экрана содержимое не обрезается, а сама шапка не налезает на блок контента.

Вопрос. Есть ли возможность только на CSS сделать так, чтобы блок контента начинался там, где заканчивается шапка и заканчивался там, где заканчивается обертка?

[Живой пример на jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/EMxDQ/)

* *Как сделать в паре с JS/jQuery - знаю. Хотелось бы найти решение (или несколько) на чистом CSS.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Этот вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/adwf4/) нужно просто подчистить под нужды (например, `display:table` применить к `<body>`), убрать ненужные обертки, `.header` заменить на `<header>`... Ну сами знаете.

Я думаю, нет ничего плохого в разбиении страницы на секции с помощью таблицы, тут это меньшее зло. Зато все по полочкам, никаких финтов ушами окромя `.content { height:100% }`. Таблицы — сила.

Хотя есть одна маленькая неприятность, на которую если наткнешься, значит *уже* запутался в верстке: Лиса не мирится с `position:relative` для table-cell-элементов (в качестве ориентира использует другого родителя).

Answer (score 0):

Мне только не понятно зачем вы используете позиционирование. я так понимаю у вас сайт получается "Резинка", используйте проценты! Пример

```
<!--wrapper begin-->
<div style="width: 100%;">

  <!--header begin-->
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 20%;">
     <h1>Place for LOGO</h1>
  </div>
  <!--header end-->

  <!--content-wrapper begin-->
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

    <!--content begin-->
    <div style"float: left; width: 70%;">
      <p>site's content</p>
    </div>
    <!--content end-->

    <!--sidebar begin-->
    <div style="float: right; width: 30%;">
      <p>sidebar's content</p>
    </div>
    <!--sidebar end-->
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <!--content-wrapper end-->

</div>
<!--wrapper end-->
```

Получится так что у вас он будет трансформировать автоматически!

Comment: Такое я делать умею. А вот сделайте так, чтобы шапка + обертка в сумме давали 100% по высоте окна.

Comment: шапка тоже должна высоту менять свою ?